# Как вызвать Intent для создания ежегодного события в календаре

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Знаю, что нужно написать что-то вроде этого

```
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,"FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10");
```

Не знаю что написать в FREQ чтобы событие повторялось ежегодно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Пункт 3.3.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10), страница 38.

```
freq = "SECONDLY" / "MINUTELY" / "HOURLY" / "DAILY" / "WEEKLY" / "MONTHLY" / "YEARLY"
```

Соответственно `YEARLY` в твоем случае.

Answer (score 0):

annually - по английски "ежегодно". попробуйте